Help Identifying a Desert War Movie
I remember seeing what was probably a north African desert war movie on TV as a kid. It would have aired in the mid to late 70's or early 80's (I'm 46).
There was a scene where a man has to retrieve a battery to put in another vehicle to get it to run. The battery he retrieves in the desert was from a broken down desert war ambulance (which I think was burned).  
I thought the actor was Yul Brynner, but none of his movies fit the genre (It's not Escape From Zahrain).  It may have just been a bald actor.  
The movie was in English.  
I've looked through all WW I and WWW II "North African War Movies" on Wikipedia as well.

I've edited to put everything in I can remember and I've researched a lot to find my own answer.  Why are you down voting?

Mr. Kennedy, thanks for the information and taking time to give a newbie some pointers.  @Paulie_D thats all I've got to give you guys, I guess I need to find somewhere else to find out.

@Paulie_D I had hope for "Ice Cold in Alex", but I watched it and it does not have the scene I described.  It does have a great scene in which they try to keep the ambulance from rolling down a hill.  I wish I could remember more of the movie, but I can't remember the vehicle that needed the ambulance battery but it was not another ambulance as I recall.

So  was it a US movie or a British one? Was it about US soldiers for instance?

@Mr.Kennedy, that's pretty funny.  I'm just a newbie that has this movie that haunts me...
